# Librdkafka: What is the purpose of rd_kafka_outq_len when there is rd_kafka_flush api

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the purpose of rd_kafka_outq_len when there is rd_kafka_flush api ?
Considering that use of rd_kafka_outq_len is to just make sure all the produced messages reach broker? Cant we just call rd_kafka_flush instead of using rd_kafka_ouq_len at all? (is it obsolete now?)

Answer (score 1):

`rd_kafka_flush()` was recently added as a convenience to application developers to help them properly shut down their producers without loosing messages.

As you mention the old `rd_kafka_outq_len()` is no longer needed for that purpose but can't be removed (without an SONAME bump) as to not break existing applications. It also allows improved flexibility over flush() when it comes to using rerouted queues.